# Closing and Opening a .exe with a batch file. Upon closing the program asks to save or not

Tags: batch-file

So I have a little a project where guests at my hotel will use a google earth that I have set up for attractions and dinning options.

I want to make it as easy as possible to navigate.

What I have is icons for each Category that is in a batch file where it closes the current GoogleEarth and opens the next Category.

When I close the Google Earth it asks me if I want to keep or discard any changes...is there an automated way of selecting discard with out clicking it?

Here is what I have now:

```
@echo off
taskkill /im googleearth.exe
@echo off 
timeout /t 5
@echo off 
START "" "C:\Users\perres\AppData\LocalLow\Google\GoogleEarth\GroceryDepartmentStores.kml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `/F` parameter to `taskkill` to forcefully terminate the app.

```
TaskKill /F /IM googleearth.exe
```

Comment: When I put the /F infront of the /IM it gives me a syntex error.

Comment: Sorry, the `/F` can't be between `/IM` and `googleearth.exe`. I fixed my answer.