# Running a program after not being used for 15 minutes

Tags: batch-file, scripting, restart

I am finishing building Google Earth for my hotel that contains different activities, shopping, and dining ideas. The owner wants it in a certain way, however, I am not a programmer and he does not want to pay for one. So I am learning as I go. I posted before about something I was wondering. ( [Closing and Opening a .exe with a batch file. Upon closing the program asks to save or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657964/closing-and-opening-a-exe-with-a-batch-file-upon-closing-the-program-asks-to-s))

My next question is; is it possible to force close the program and open in up if the program was not used for 15 minutes? Could some one point me into the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `qprocess` or `tasklist` commands and there's a small chance to not have neither of these (you should check it)

here's an example script

```
@echo off
rem -- checking if the machine is x32 or x64
rem -- google earth clinet is x32
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) (
  set "ge=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth\client\googleearth.exe"
) else (
   set "ge=C:\Program Files\Google\Google Earth\client\googleearth.exe"
)

rem -- better approach is to check the registry bu here I'll use default folders

:repeat
tasklist | find /i "googleearth" && (
   rem -- program is running
   rem -- we need to wait and repeat
   rem -- waiting 15 minutes
   ping 192.0.2.1 -n 1 -w 90000 >nul 2>nul
   goto :repeat
) || (
  rem -- program is not running 
  rem -- we need to start it again

  start "" "%ge%" 

)
```

Comment: Would this be a separate file to the ones that I have?